# Kubernetes localhost external requests doesn't work

Tags: kubernetes, docker-desktop

I am using Docker desktop app for windows with inbox kubernetes installed (throught "Settings" -> "Kubernetes" -> "Enable Kubernetes").
The problem is I can't get external requests go throught external service of Kubernetes (I also tryied ingresses with simple nginx and it doesn't work too).
So basicaly it doesn't see localhost no matter what paths (if I use ingress) and/or ports I use.
What I already did:

1. Installed ingress control from: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#quick-start.
2. applied yamls below in kubectl via commands: kubectl apply -f {x}.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mongodb-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  mongo-root-username: base64 just some value
  mongo-root-password: base64 just some value
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mongodb-configmap
data:
  database_url: mongodb-service
```

```
#mongodb.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongodb
  labels:
    app: mongodb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongodb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongodb
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongodb
        image: mongo
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017           
        env:
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-secret
              key: mongo-root-username          
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-secret
              key: mongo-root-password
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongodb-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongodb
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
```

```
#mongo-express.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo-express
  labels:
    app: mongo-express
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo-express
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo-express
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongo-express
        image: mongo-express
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081           
        env:
        - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-secret
              key: mongo-root-username          
        - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-secret
              key: mongo-root-password
        - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-configmap
              key: database_url
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo-express-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongo-express
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8081
      targetPort: 8081
      nodePort: 31000
```

3. I did double check all mapings and it seems to be okay, however when I am trying to open http://localhost:31000 nothing happens. Ofcourse all pods are up and running.
   [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
4. I also did hard resets of Kubernetes in Docker Desktop and rebooted operation system multiple times, but nothing did help.

Comment: Please add output from `kubectl get pods`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is when you specify service `type: LoadBalancer` you should not specify `nodePort:`

Just use Mongo Express as

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo-express-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongo-express
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8081
      targetPort: 8081
```

Then go to http://localhost:8081 and everything will work

If you want use Node Port you need to change service type to `type: NodePort` and add `nodePort: 31000`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo-express-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongo-express
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8081
      targetPort: 8081
      nodePort: 31000
```

Then you Mongo Express will be available at http://localhost:31000

**Note**: Default basic auth credentials:

- username: `admin`
- password: `pass`

---

Below full yaml used for testing

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mongodb-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  mongo-root-username: YWRtaW4xMjM=
  mongo-root-password: YWRtaW4xMjM=

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mongodb-configmap
data:
  database_url: 'mongodb-service'
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongodb
  labels:
    app: mongodb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongodb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongodb
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongodb
        image: mongo
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017           
        env:
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-secret
              key: mongo-root-username          
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-secret
              key: mongo-root-password
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongodb-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongodb
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo-express
  labels:
    app: mongo-express
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo-express
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo-express
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongo-express
        image: mongo-express
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081           
        env:
        - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-secret
              key: mongo-root-username
        - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-secret
              key: mongo-root-password
        - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-configmap
              key: database_url
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo-express-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongo-express
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8081
      targetPort: 8081
      nodePort: 31000
```

Comment: thank you for reply @zori! I applied your yaml and in chrome now I have authorization pop-up. But when I enter admin123 user and password (which you encoded in secret) it give me 401 code unauthorized.
Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: Credential you can get from mongo express pod logs default is username:`admin` password:`pass`

Comment: it worked!!! Huge thanks. Spent 10 hours straight on it today...